# how to extract a javascript variable from a function

Tags: javascript

I want to retrieve the variable x from the function, but this code does not work
who has an idea

thank you

```
function myFunction(){
  var x = document.getElementById("nom").value;
  //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =x ;

 return x;
}

response = myFunction();

document.getElementById("deux").innerHTML =response ;
```

```
<form class="form">
<label>Entre ton nom</label>
<input type="text" id="nom" name="Nom" placeholder="Nom" value="" class="form-control">
<input type="button" name="Envoyer" class="btn btn-default" value="Envoyer" onclick="myFunction();">
</form>

 <script src="test-envois.js"></script>
   <p id="deux"></p>
  <p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What happens instead? What type of element is `nom`?

Comment: Thank you for the answer
the nom comes from an input of a form in html. with my code nothing is displayed on the html

Comment: Look at the browser console and paste the error in your question.

Comment: I have no error I will post my html code

Comment: What does your `test-envois.js` file look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what can I see in the code is that you want to add the response to the deux  id when you click on the button
The problem in that is that response executes the moment you load the page.
You need to add that logic inside the function like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("nom").value;
    //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =x ;
    // let response = myFunction();

    document.getElementById("deux").innerHTML = x;
}
```

And now it executes when you click the button

Comment: Thank you for the answer ... but I will explain better, in my file I have another function which displays a basket (displaybasket) for a purchase order and I need the variable x to perform calculations in the function displaysbasket.
the myFunction function allows me to retrieve the variable name of my form

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you want whatever the user inputs in the form "nom" to be displayed in the paragraph tag "deux"?

if that’s the case you could just do:

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("nom").value;
document.getElementById("deux").innerHTML = x;
}
```

you can enclose all the code into one function, no need to separate it

Comment: no I would like everything that the user types in nom to be displayed in another displaybasket function . the myFunction function is just for me to retrieve the nom

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(){
  var x = document.getElementById("nom").value;
 affichepanier(x);
 
}

function affichepanier(val)
{
  var variableOfFunction1 = val;
  document.getElementById("deux").innerHTML =variableOfFunction1 ;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: @Arthur please brief your answer